# aggregate ordered rows in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, aggregate, analytics, rows

i have a table in **hive** with 4 columns like this:

```
row_id| user_id|product_id| duration
1       1       product1    3
2       1       product1    1
3       1       product2    6
4       1       product3    2
5       1       product1    4
6       1       product4    3
7       1       product4    5
8       1       product4    7
9       2       product4    3
10      2       product4    6
```

i want to  **aggregate** rows of the same product for each user, sum the duration and count the clicks only if they are **consequent** in order

```
row_id| user_id|product_id |duration_per_product |clicks_per_product
1       1       product1    4                       2
2       1       product2    6                       1
3       1       product3    2                       1
4       1       product1    4                       1
5       1       product4    15                      3
6       2       product4    9                       2
```

any ideas how to do that in hive 1.1.0?

group by obviously doesn't work because i don't want to group products if they are consequent , i have tried case,lag and lead but didn't work!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this is something you would want to do in a loop, **hive is not very suitable for these kind of problems**.

That being said, here is an approach that should work:

Suppose this is our dataset

```
1       1       product1    3
2       1       product1    1
3       1       product2    6
4       1       product1    4
```

Identify starter rows: `1,3,4`
This can be done by doing a left join on id=id+1 and seeing whether user and product match.

Join everything onto these starters by user and product:

```
1 1
1 2
1 4
3 3
4 1
4 2
4 4
```

Filter out things that are in the wrong order (starter after row), remaining are:

```
1 1
1 2
1 4
3 3
4 4
```

Group to find the maximum valid starter for each row,  remaining will be:

```
1 1 
1 2
3 3
4 4
```

Now join to reattach the relevant dimensions

```
1 1 3
1 2 1
3 3 6
4 4 4
```

Now you can get the results by grouping on the starter id.

```
1 4
3 6
4 4
```

Of course you can now choose to use another join to attach the name of the product.

```
1 product1 4
3 product2 6
4 product1 4
```

And that is all!

Comment: Note that I left the actual queries as an excercise to the reader, but based on the way the question was written that should be ok.

Comment: thanks for your help , but i have millions of rows , so i can't do this process,          i'm expecting something like:          select *,case when product=previous_product then  sum(1) over
(partition by user_id,product_id order by row_id ROWS BETWEEN 
    1 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) else 1 end as clicks_per_product from (
        select *,lag(product,1) over 
         (partition by user_id order by row_id) as previous_product 
         from myTable) t order by row_id;

Comment: @AbedShareef I don't think there is a quicker way to do it, unless you can (pre)process your table with a programming language or so. The good news is that if you only have millions of rows this method could still work. (I did not try it in hive, but I used a similar trick in PIG before).

Comment: i have tried your method after all, it's a long process but it works perfectly , thank you!